# WPF TextBox not updating in UI every time PropertyChanged is raised

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, viewmodel

I saw a lot of other questions around this, but none seemed to pertain, since my binding *is* working, but just not every time.

I have a TextBox in my XAML.

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ProgressMessages, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

It is bound to a Dependency Property () in the ViewModel.

```
private string progressMessages;
public string ProgressMessages
{
    get { return progressMessages; }
    set
    {
        progressMessages = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ProgressMessages);
    }
}
```

I have a method that updates ProgressMessages twice.  This method is bound to a Command that runs as a result of a button click.

```
private void GenerateInvoices()
{
    ProgressMessages = "Starting execution of Generate Invoices on the HBApp Server";
    int numGenerated = GenerateInvoices(masterProcessId);  // runs for a few seconds
    ProgressMessages += "\n" + numGenerated.ToString() + " invoices have been generated.";
}
```

Problem is, the first time `ProgressMessages` is modified in the above method, the change is not reflected in the UI immediately.  The TextBox remains blank.  But the second time I modify it, both strings show up at the same time.  It's not much of a progress indicator if all the progress messages show up all at once at the end!

**What I tried:**

I stepped through in the debugger, and ensured that `RaisePropertyChanged` was indeed invoked for both of the Sets - it was.

I added `Mode=TwoWay`, and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, but to no avail.

**Question**

So what is it that's preventing the TextBox from showing the updated text *every* time I assign a new value to `ProgressMessages`?

Could this be the Dispatcher deciding to lump multiple UI updates into one?  But I need it to update right away.

Comment: I'm by no means an expert, but I don't expect it's able to update while the UI thread is blocked.

Comment: @Chris is right. You need to call `GenerateInvoices()` asynchronously.

Comment: Holy smokes, thanks for the quick answers.  I didn't realize that the UI thread would be locked in this situation.  Is it because it's executing a command attached to a button?  I guess I thought using MVVM instead of OnClick in code-behind somehow removed the UI locking of the past.  I can definitely do it asynchronously.  Thanks all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Task.Run to do the job on another thread (your UI Thread is locked hence you can't see the change until it's free again).

```
private void GenerateInvoices()
{
   Task.Run(()=>
    {
        ProgressMessages = "Starting execution of Generate Invoices on the HBApp Server";
        int numGenerated = GenerateInvoices(masterProcessId);  // runs for a few seconds
        ProgressMessages += "\n" + numGenerated.ToString() + " invoices have been generated.";
    });
}
```

consider using [async await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) if you need to wait until certain task will finished.